# Unable to save the changes in SublimeLinter.sublime.setting-User after making changes

Tags: sublimetext3, settings, linter

I keep getting this error:

```
Error trying to parse settings: Expected character in Packages\User\SublimeLinter.sublime-settings:69:2
```

I am attaching the screenshots, also I am running version 3.1.1 build 3176.

I added/made changes here

```
"error_color": "D02000"
```

Here is my code for user settings:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AS0u.jpg)

Comment: I fixed formatting.

Comment: Thank Bsquare, can anyone help on this question please?